# How do I count all items for one table in a multiple INNER JOIN SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am inner joining multiple tables based on matching primary and foreign keys. One of the fields requires an aggregate count function that I'm having trouble with.

```
SELECT qry_Facility.Name, tbl_FacilityDates.DateChecked, Count(tbl_ActionItems.ActionItemsNameID)
FROM (qry_Facility INNER JOIN tbl_FacilityDates ON qry_Facility.NameID = tbl_FacilityDates.DatesNameID) INNER JOIN tbl_ActionItems ON qry_Facility.NameID = tbl_ActionItems.ActionItemsNameID
WHERE ((tbl_FacilityDates.Type=)”Restaurants”);
```

The SQL above produces an error of "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Name' as part of an aggregate function."

If I remove the aggregate count function, the INNER JOIN table works except that the action items are listed individually instead of counted together.

```
,...tbl_ActionItems.ActionItemsNameID
```

I think the error is indicating me to use a GROUP BY clause, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are missing `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Should each field have a `GROUP BY` or just the tbl_ActionItems.ActionItemsNameID? Access SQL seems to require me to have a `GROUP BY` for each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT qry_Facility.Name, 
tbl_FacilityDates.DateChecked, 
Count(tbl_ActionItems.ActionItemsNameID) 
FROM (qry_Facility 
INNER JOIN tbl_FacilityDates 
ON qry_Facility.NameID = tbl_FacilityDates.DatesNameID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_ActionItems 
ON qry_Facility.NameID = tbl_ActionItems.ActionItemsNameID 
WHERE ((tbl_FacilityDates.Type=)”Restaurants”) 
Group by qry_Facility.Name,
    tbl_FacilityDates.DateChecked
```

Comment: This worked for me! I was trying to `GROUP BY` the aggregate field itself, but it turns out you should `GROUP BY` every other field!